# Power of a random variable gamma distributed

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution

If a random variable $X$, follows a Gamma distribution. I know that the distribution is given by:
$$F_X(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{x/\theta}u^{\alpha-1}e^{-u}du$$

Now, If I need to consider the random variable $Y=X^{1/\tau}$ with $\tau>0$, I can conclude that
$$P(Y\leq y)=P(X^{1/\tau}\leq y)=P(X\leq y^{\tau})=F_X(y^{\tau})$$

It means that
$$F_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{y^\tau/\theta}u^{\alpha-1}e^{-u}du$$
in conclusion
$$F_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\gamma(\alpha,\frac{y^\tau}{\theta})$$

However, performing a simple computations gives different results.
Supposing $\alpha=3,\theta=5,\tau=2$

First, I consider the fact:
$Y=X^{\frac{1}{\tau}}$ then,
$$P(X^{1/\tau}\leq y)=P(X\leq y^\tau)=F_X(y^tau)$$
Let,

Code Corrected, this code works perfectly and shows the desired property.

```
tau<-2
alpha<-3
theta<-5
y<-4
pgamma(y^(tau),shape=alpha,scale=theta)

####Using the incomplete gamma function
###The incomplete gamma function is given by: pgamma((y^tau)/theta,shape = alpha)*(gamma(alpha))

(1/gamma(alpha))*pgamma((y^tau)/theta,shape = alpha)*(gamma(alpha))
```

Gives different values. What is wrong?

I am not clear with my solution since I found in another post that it is
$$F_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{(x/\theta)^\tau}u^{\alpha-1}e^{-u}du$$ and I am not clear why is also the scale parameter with the exponent.

Comment: I think your solution is correct.

Comment: What is $\tau$?

Comment: $\tau$ is only a number greater than zero, I want to find the distribution of a random variable gamma to the power tau

Comment: **Your calculation does not implement the formula you gave:** by setting the scale to $\theta,$ your are computing the distribution of $x^{1/\tau}/\theta$ rather than that of $(x/\theta)^{1/\tau}.$

Comment: Perhaps consulting our answers about the Generalized Gamma distribution will clarify what it is and how to work with it.  Here is a search that looks for highly-upvoted relevant answers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22generalized%20gamma%22%20-glm%20-bayesian%20is%3aanswer%20score%3a1.